# Factoring in $\mathbb{F}_3$

Tags: linear-algebra, galois-theory

I am trying to factor the polynomial $t^9-t$ in the field with three elements $0,1,2$. I think that the factors $(t)(t)(t)(t)(t)(t)(t)(t)(t-1)$ are all irreducible but for some reason this seemed too simple for a problem from the book I am working from. Any help or hints welcome!

Comment: If you multiply all those factors, you get $t^9-t^8$, not $t^9-1$.

Comment: Note that $2^9-2\equiv 0\pmod{3}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have:

$$\begin{align}
t^9-t&=t(t^8-1)\\&=t(t^4+1)(t^4-1)\\&=t(t^4+1)(t^2+1)(t^2-1)\\&=t(t^4+1)(t^2+1)(t+1)(t-1)\end{align}$$

It is easy to see (right?) that $t^4+1$ and $t^2+1$ have no linear factors in $\Bbb F_3$. So it remains to try and factorise $t^4+1$ into two quadratic terms:
$$t^4+1=(t^2+at+b)(t^2+ct+d)$$

By equating coefficients modulo $3$, you get four equations in $a,b,c,d$ which are easily seen to be soluble. Try it and see!

Comment: One may also observe that modulo three
$$t^4+1=(t^4-2t^2+1)-t^2=(t^2-1)^2-t^2,$$
which can be factored using the same *difference of squares* trick you already used twice.

Answer (score 2):

Using the usual rules that apply in any field you can get down to $t^9-t=t(t^8-1)=t(t^4+1)(t^4-1)=t(t^4+1)(t^2+1)(t^2-1)=t(t^4+1)(t^2+1)(t+1)(t-1)$.

However, you aren't done at that point.  While $t^2+1$ is irreducible ($\Bbb{F}_3$ has no square root of $-1$), $t^4+1$ must factor into two quadratics over $\Bbb{F}_3$ since the degree $2$ extension $\Bbb{F}_9$ has fourth roots of $-1$.  (All finite fields have cyclic multiplicative groups, so having $8$ non-zero elements means $\Bbb{F}_9$ has primitive eighth roots of unity, and hence fourth roots of $-1$.)  So the minimal polynomials for fourth roots of $-1$ have degree two and multiply together to get you $t^4+1$.  So the hint is: factor $t^4+1$ into two quadratics over $\Bbb{F}_3$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: factor it in stages
$$t^9-t$$
$$t(t^8-1)$$
$$t(t^4+1)(t^4-1)$$
$$t(t^4+1)(t^2-1)(t^2+1)$$
$$t(t-1)(t+1)(t^2+1)(t^4+1)$$